# Firebase Realtime Database Connection Refresh

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two controllers one is login and another is tableView Controller where I am displaying users information.
When app starts it first checks if user is logged in or not.
If user is logged in, it will fetch users data from firebase realtime database and display in tableView. If not then it will show login controller where user have to login using email and password.
Now once i logged in i can see users data into TableViewController from firebase, But if i closed app without log out and open it after some time like 20 min later or next day when the app launch it check if user is logged in or not in my case it shows logged in and display tableViewController but it is empty it does not fetch users data from firebase realtime database. 
If i will logged out and login again then i can see users data coming from firebase but if i close app and open it again after sometime it will not show any data into my tableViewController.
I dont want users to login every time in application to get firebase data if user is logged in it must show the data from firebase real time database.

Following is code to check if user is logged in or not

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil{

        print("Logout call")
        perform(#selector(handleLogout), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
    }else{
        print("User Logged In")
        fethUserAndSetupNavbarTitle()
    }
```

following code will get data from firebase realtime database.

```
 guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let dbReference = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(uid)

    dbReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
        in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            let user = Users(dictionary: dictionary)
            print("setup navbar called")

            self.setupNavBarWithUser(user)

        }

    }, withCancel: { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    })
```

Please let me know if i am unable to describe the problem.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might know what the problem is.
The Firebase Token gets disabled after one hour or so. 
You need to enable Token Service API to allow refreshing the token once it expires. 
Go to https://console.developers.google.com/ , click onto "Enable APIs And Services", search for Token Service API and enable it.